# How do I get back into the Confiscated Goods vault?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I've been attempting to complete riddler challenges, and noticed that there are at least two collectibles inside TYGER's confiscated goods vault that I missed (map below).  I've looked for a way in, but found the main door locked and the tunnel Catwoman used to enter entirely blocked off by Poison Ivy's plants.  How the heck do I get back in there?

[image: Riddler collectibles in confiscated goods vault]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it turns out, the riddler collectibles are not actually inside the vault.  The solution to the riddle is

> the door of the vault,

and the trophy is

> on top of the building next to the vault.